# DryIOC Non-lazy resolution

Tags: dryioc

How can I disable lazy resolution in DryIOC?  I need some of my singletons to be instantiated immediately.

At the moment I'm doing all my register calls, and then having another block of resolve calls for the ones I need instantiated in the beginning.  But its gettting a bit unwieldy.

Comment: Immediately when? When Register your singletons? Then you need all dependencies to be available before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may mark the registrations with specific metadata, let's say with `public enum AutoActivate { It }`. Then discover the marked registrations and resolve them in preferrable time:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(Reuse.Singleton, setup: Setup.With(AutoActivate.It));
container.Register<IBar, Bar>(Reuse.Singleton); // don't activate

// when suitable
var activatedServices = container.GetServiceRegistrations()
    .Where(r => r.Factory.Setup.Metadata is AutoActivate)
    .OrderBy(r => r.FactoryRegistrationOrder)
    .GroupBy(r => r.FactoryRegistrationOrder, (f, r) => r.First())
    .Select(r => container.Resolve(r.ServiceType, r.OptionalServiceKey));
```

Comment: I would add `.ToArray()` call to the end so `IEnumerable<object>` will be instantiated along with services inside